# Trying to ask for the exact time when I can tour an apartment which I am interesting renting

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

I was requesting a tour of an apartment I am interested in renting. The future landlord said I could come later afternoon after the cleaning is done. So I want to ask for the exact (or at least approximate) time when the cleaning is done, and the place is ready for me to take a tour. I was struggling to say that, here are a few ways that I have thought of:

1. "when exactly can I come to take a tour?"
2. "what's the ETA on the cleaning?"

Can you folks also suggest a few other ways to say this?

Comment: THe first asks for the information you want. The second asks for some different information, in the hope that you can work out the information you want from it. Why would you do that?

Comment: "What time do you suggest?"

Answer (score 1):

"ETA" sounds a little silly.  Like you are some kind of military guy.  Unless you are talking about an "Expected Time of Arrival", don't use ETA.

The first is fine.  Or you could confirm a time and let them respond

> I'll come for the tour at 4 pm.  See you then.

If 4pm is too early, it is up to the estate agent to contact you.

Comment: thanks! if I just want to ask what the earliest / soonest time I can take a toor, how should I ask that?

Comment: You could say "what is the earliest / soonest time I can take a tour?"  or as I said the first is find, you could say ""when exactly can I come to take a tour?"